# Is there a background-width property in CSS?

Tags: css, list, menu, background

I have a vertical menu using lists (li) and I've got it changing background color on hover.

```
#limenu:hover {background-color:#000}
```

However, I don't want the background to fill 100% width. Is there a way of setting the background width or creating a padding on both sides?

Comment: How about using a padding on the ol/ul container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a [**background-size property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) that does exactly what you want in CSS3. But, it will be a few years until this is so widely implemented that you can develop for it safely.

Until then, bytenik's suggestion (or resizing the background image server-side) is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way of setting background width. However, you can simulate this effect in this case by setting a padding and then using overflow to allow your content to overflow the box. The background will still be constrained by the box even if the content is not.

Answer (score 0):

There's a background-size.

i.e.

background-size: cover;